# Simple client program

Tags: python, sockets

`server.py` is fine and I use array to send data:

```
for i in range(0,len(outputdata)):       
    connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i])
    connectionSocket.close()
```

But my client don't work(print nothing):

```
#import socket module
from socket import *

serverName = '127.0.0.1'    
serverPort = 9999    
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)    
clientSocket.connect((serverName,serverPort))    
request = raw_input('Input the filename:')   
clientSocket.send(request)    
while (clientSocket.recv(1024)):
    print clientSocket.recv(1024)
clientSocket.close()
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: How do you open `connectionSocket`

Comment: connectionSocket,addr =  serverSocket.accept()

Comment: Server.py is not fine if you close the socket in the first loop. It sends one thing. Receiver throws away first receive and second recieve won't get anything since the socket was closed.

Comment: but I can c the array in browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `clientSocket.recv(1024)` is a command that will fetch available data.

from Python Docs:

> Receive data from the socket. The return value is a string
>   representing the data received. The maximum amount of data to be
>   received at once is specified by bufsize. See the Unix manual page
>   recv(2) for the meaning of the optional argument flags; it defaults to
>   zero.

To understand it better, your server is sending some data, the client receives that data and holds it in a buffer, the command will go to that buffer and **pop** the data (with max of 1024 at your code) so if you have 1024 bytes waiting in the buffer the first `recv(1024)` command will get all the data in the buffer and the second `recv(1024)` will be empty.

A good solution was suggested by @gnibbler.

Remember calling `clientSocket.recv(1024)` without saving it's return value it's like popping from a stack without saving the value.

Answer (score 0):

The first `clientSocket.recv(1024)` is throwing away those bytes

```
while (clientSocket.recv(1024)):
    print clientSocket.recv(1024)
```

You need to save them into a variable like this

```
while True:
    data = clientSocket.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    print data
```